# Pythonic way to import modules from packages

Tags: python, scipy, python-import

Is there any difference, subtle or not so subtle, between the effects of the following import statements? I have found both used in example programs and sure enough, they both seem to work. It would go against the grain of Python's "there is only one way to do stuff" if they were totally equivalent in function, so I'm puzzled. I'm just starting out in Python and trying to keep good habits. So for instance, for the interpolate module in the scipy package ...

```
from scipy import interpolate as spi
```

or

```
import scipy.interpolate as spi
```

both appear to put the interpolate module in the current namespace as spi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of taste, really.

In this particular case, I would use `import scipy.interpolate as spi`, to remember that `interpolate` is a submodule of `scipy`. If I were to import a function from a module, I would use `from module import function`.

The only thing is, be consistent with the convention you choose.

Comment: I kind of prefer the "import package.module as shortname" version, but wondered if the "from package import module" had anything to recommend it. I don't "from module import function" whether renaming it or not, as I like to have visibility of the module and function name in my code. So it seems that "import full_module_name as shortname", whether full_module_name has a package prefix or not, is the consistent way to do it. I use a consistent set of shortnames, that seem to crop up in many sources:- np, sp, tk, plt for instance, npr for numpy.random etc.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no difference between the two statements, both put the exact same object into your module namespace (`globals()`), under the exact same name.

They go about it in slightly different ways but the end-result is the same.

Essentially, the first does:

```
from scipy import interpolate
spi = interpolate
del interpolate
```

and the second comes down to

```
import scipy.interpolate
spi = scipy.interpolate
del scipy
```

and in the end all you have is the `spi` name bound to the `interpolate` function.

Personally, I would not rename the function like that, I'd keep it as `import scipy` and use `scipy.interpolate`, clearly communicating where the object comes from throughout the code, *or* I'd use `from scipy import interpolate`.

Renaming the object may make it easier to type for you, but may make it harder for you or others to grok later on when you revisit this code after months of absence.

Comment: I should have made it clearer that interpolate was the module, not the function. I end up using f=spi.interp1d(...

Comment: @Neil_UK: the comment still applies, wether it's a module or a function. :-) Adjusted the wording.